# Launching high-detailed Ordnance Survey maps in QGIS 3x

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, ordnance-survey

I would like to have the Ordnance Survey maps tiles in QGIS.

Most of the sources from the web, from where we can import the maps are not in high detail.

The scale, which I am interested in is 1:500 (zoom level 15). 
One reasonable source, from where I can enter these maps is:

mapping.cityoflondon.gov.uk/geocortex/mapping/?viewer=compass&runworkflowbyid=Switch_layer_themes&LayerTheme=Show%20the%20Explore%20The%20City%20layers

I have got the option to export them as the GeoTIFF, but I am restricted to the viewing area only.

[image]

Is there another source, where I can get these maps possibly for free as XYZ tiles of alternatively the WMS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, at that scale you are looking for OS MasterMap which are (currently) the "Crown Jewels" of GB spatial data. OS makes most of it's money from licencing that data to (mostly) other government agencies.

If you don't want to pay then your best bet is the [OS Zoomstack data](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/products/open-zoomstack) which you can style and tile exactly how you want.

Comment: I know your link.
The problem is, that when I tick the box on the right-hand side, then there is no reaction & download at all. It applies to all of the stuff displayed there. Do you know how to get it around and download this file in the given format?

Comment: You go to the bottom and click continue and fill in the stupid form and they send you alink

Comment: Great, thank you. Sadly I was a few times before and I didn't sweep down to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

The [OS Data Hub](https://osdatahub.os.uk/) (launching on 1st July) will include ZXY and WMTS services as part of the OS Maps API.

The OS Maps API is scalable, making it capable of providing an overview of Great Britain all the way down to street level. It does this by combining the new OS Open Zoomstack with the detailed OS MasterMap Topography Layer.

The service includes a Premium Plan... which offers unlimited access to the OpenData APIs; along with free access to Premium data APIs up to ~30K transactions per month [1 transaction = 15 map tiles].