# MbTiles not visible in QGIS 3x

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mbtiles

I recently downloaded the OpenZoomstack mbtiles maps from OS, following the query:

[Launching high-detailed Ordnance Survey maps in QGIS 3x](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364514/launching-high-detailed-ordnance-survey-maps-in-qgis-3x)

but it looks like the QGIS can't open them properly.

The way how to load the mbtiles in QGIS I found here:
https://support.maptiler.com/i77-open-maps-in-qgis

but it looks like the file is completely invisible in the program.

[image]

I thought that problem might lay in the coordinates system. However, the provider set the following CRS:
EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected

The same as I set in properties for my project.

The layer is visible in the layers box but not on the map.

Where can be the problem then?

Comment: What version of QGIS do you use? For vector tiles in MBtiles, you need either QGIS 3.13 (QGIS development version) or to use https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/vector_tiles_reader/

Comment: OK I will try this plugin then :) Thanks.
I am using 3.12