Ordanence Survey MBtiles (Vector Tiles) are not visible in QGIS
I've recently downloaded a mbtiles (vector tiles) layer from Ordnance Survey. But the problem is I'm unable to view it using QGIS (I have to view it there as all other layers I need to use for my project will also be there). I'm only able to view it when I try adding it as a vector layer, however when I drag & drop it nothing is being shown. The only thing left which I feel like might be reason why I cannot see this layer is zoom levels. As you can see below in the screenshot they look a bit weird, and I think they are the main reason why I cannot view this layer. Both minzoom and maxzoom appear to be -1.

Has anyone else experienced this issue before and got something to suggest?

Are you using the MBtiler plugin? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365067/mbtiles-not-visible-in-qgis-3x

There are better formats if you want to display the data in QGis

Mbtiler plugin is sort of out-of-date, but still I added it from a dowloanded zip file. But no luck.

Also regarding other (and also better) formats,   this is a big dataset (UK wide) and I just need to quickly use it without the need of any further processing for converting it to another format, because I plan to update it every 2-3 months.

did this https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/user-guides/getting-started-with-vector-tiles.pdf answer your question ?

And if you have internet access (ie. don't need to work offline) this solution will let you use the data without downloading it : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387847/connecting-qgis-to-os-vector-tile-api

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/user-guides/getting-started-with-vector-tiles.pdf  I  tried this one a few days ago, I even dowloaded the specific version but unfortunately it did not.

regarding using os api for vector tiles onlone, I'm also aware of this possibility but unfortunately api usage is subject to a limit. Otherwise of course it's the best option. But a number of users requesting those tiles everyday, multiple times in a day would dramatically reduce the number of days in a month we have access to this API

Also another point maybe worth mentioning is I am able to view them by using for instance this application called Mbtiles Viwer https://github.com/Akylas/mbview-rs . But I cannot view them in QGIS
